# Django DRF without db

Tags: python, django

I need to build a rest api using django. On GET requests my tool has to captures parameters from url and invoke a function for their manipulation.

For example: on input url `myapp/name=john&birthdate=11July`, the function `compute(name,birthdate)` computes a transformation on parameters returning a json as output. I don't understand how to proceed, considering that each tutorial i followed is about db interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urls.py:

```
url(r'^myapp/$', views.myapp, name='myapp'),
```

views.py

```
def myapp(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    birthdate = request.GET.get('birthdate', None)

    if name and birthdate:
        result = compute(name, birthdate)
        return result
    return None
```

You don't need a database for that. Although you need a database for Django to work.

Comment: Thanks.  In the structure of Django DFR where it's supposed to place each utility .py file? For example, compute is a function of scriptX.py. I suppose it  would be better to create  a folder with utilities script.

Comment: You really don't need to use DRF for that, if you're not using the default functionality anyway.

Comment: If you're not gonna do anything DB related, yeah, you don't.

Comment: In views.py where should i place the code? Into a class definition? I get the error **`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.**

Comment: Are you using class based views?

Comment: yes, but i just clicked on the first example i found. I've found  only example with db and retrive, but it's not what i need!

Comment: Yeah, I gave you the function based view example. You'll need to put it into `get` method of your class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views